# Code works as desired, but still warnings

Tags: php, html, json

I'm printing data from a JSON file.

Here's the string I'm printing:

```
$industry = $data->response->result->Candidates->row[$i]->FL[4]->content;
```

Certain keys for the FL value don't exist. It's works fine, as I have an if sentence to take care of it.

```
<? if (!is_null($industry) == true): ?>
      <td><? echo $industry; ?></td>
<? else: ?>
      <td><? echo ' '; ?></td>
<? endif; ?>
```

It still gives me weird errors though. I thought that my if sentence would eliminate exactly these two, but no:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 4
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: You are getting the error when trying to set $industry, not when you are trying to use it.

Check the value exists before you try assign it to the variable

Comment: Protip: `if(!is_null($industry) == true) == if($industry)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Notice: Undefined offset: 4` means your array does not have a key 4.You can check it with an isset

```
 if (isset($data->response->result->Candidates->row[$i]->FL[4])) {
   $industry = $data->response->result->Candidates->row[$i]->FL[4]->content;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Both notices you are getting are from the following line:

```
$industry = $data->response->result->Candidates->row[$i]->FL[4]->content;
```

In order to avoid this, you shuld check that the index is present:

```
$FL = $data->response->result->Candidates->row[$i]->FL;
$industry = array_key_exists(4, $FL) ? $FL[4]->content : null;
```

And then you could check:

```
if ($industry) {
    //do something crazy when $industry is present.
} else {
    //do something crazy when $industry was not present.
}
```